# Explain scoring in lucene while sorting involved

Tags: sorting, search, lucene, full-text-search, scoring

I am getting null value in topDocs.scoreDocs for some documents while searching in lucene index.
Please **explain me about value in [ ]** in topDocs.scoreDocs

```
SortField sortFieldObj = new SortField(sortField, SortField.STRING, sortOrder);
Sort sort = new Sort(sortFieldObj);
TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search(query, null, sizeNeeded, sort);
Document docNew = searcher.doc(topDocs.scoreDocs[i].doc);
System.out.println(topDocs.scoreDocs[i]);
```

output:

> doc=2 score=NaN[**null**]
>
> doc=44 score=NaN[**testString**]

Answer (score 7):

Well, the reson is indirectly you told Lucene to ignore its document scores and use your own sort order. Scoring is used to bring topdocs, but you chose to bring docs in the sort order you specified, hence NAN.

If you want to force Lucene to give you scores when you specified your own sort order use another overloaded method for search :

```
search(Query query, Filter filter, int n,
                             Sort sort, boolean doDocScores, boolean doMaxScore)
```

If doDocScores is true then the score of each hit will becomputed and  returned. 
If doMaxScore true then the maximum score over all collected hits will be computed.

So you would do something like : searcher.search(query, null, sizeNeeded, sort,true,true);

Comment: Thanks for your comment Arun..But my question is about null within [ ] and getting field's value within [ ]. i have highlighted that in question now

Comment: Also what is meant by scoreDocs when own sort order involved